# How to send and snooze an email in Gmail in one action?

Tags: gmail

I have read this https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69906/how-to-find-an-email-in-gmail-that-was-snoozed-in-google-inbox but it's not exactly what I want to do.

I want a way to write an email and send it while adding it to snooze as I use snooze as a reminder for follow up.

What I have in mind is a bit like Gmail's native send later.

So it will be like send + snooze with a dropdown that lets me choose when to get reminded by this email.

Is this possible?

Currently, the way I do it is after I send email, I then go to sent folder and snooze the email.

I want to skip these extra clicks.

I’m looking for either a built in feature (which I highly doubt) or an extension that does this

At the worst case an extension I can modify its open source code to adapt to my use case

Comment: I'd recommend asking there instead of here as it's more "how to improve that web service" than "I'm looking for software"